# How to hide unused id from URL routing in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

In action my parameter can be empty. So how can I hide if it is `null` .
I want to handled on controller side.

```cs
[Route("2")]
[HttpGet]        
public ActionResult Index(string eID)
{
    return View();
}
```

The URL I'm getting like `/2?eID`. My `eID` can be `null`. I want to hide if `eID` is `null` in the URL.
I'm accessing this  action using `var url = '@Url.Action("action", "Controller",new { eID = "sampleURI"})';` from another action view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the following route:

```cs
[HttpGet("/2/{eID?}")]
public ActionResult Index(string eID)
{
   return View();
}
```

The `?` character in `{eID?}` defines `eID` as optional.

Therefore, you can use the following URLs:

- `/2`
- `/2/some-text`
- `/2?eID=some-text`

An additional information you can find here: [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: i'm accessing this  action using var url = '@Url.Action("action", "Controller",new { eID = "sampleURI"})'; from another action view. So that i think '/' also getting displayed. How can hide '/'as well

Comment: @CalmBoy: If The `@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { eID = "sampleURI" })` will generate the following URI: `/2/sampleURI`. So what is the problem?